# Android: set the height of 1 row different from others in GridView

Tags: android, gridview

I'm been searching for a long time, how to set the height of **only 1 row** different from the others:

```
1 2 3
- - -
4 5 6
- - -
7 8 9
```

I have 9 items :
1, 2 have a height of 50dp. All other items have a height of 30 dp.

I found a solution to have the first row to 50dp, but in this way, item 3 becomes 50dp, too.

I am able to find "3" in the gridview adapter, but when I change its height by `LayoutParam` to 30dp, the vertical spacing changes. I found that the vertical spacing aligns always with the shortest element (which I do not want).

what should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put your gridview item inside other layout e.g Linearlayout, and inside your adapter whenever you find the 3rd item just change the layout_bounds of that custom item.

```
<LinearLayout

    <CustomItemLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and inside gridviewadapter

```
if(position == 3){
    LayoutParams newParams = ...;
    holder.customview.setlayoutparam();
}
```

Comment: hi, i have updated my question, could you give it a look?